# C# force register/overwrite hotkeys

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, hotkeys

I want to force register/overwrite hotkeys...so this code is working fine but it fail's when that hotkey already register for the other application...

so I want to overwrite hotkey is it possible?

```
[DllImport("user32", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

enum KeyModifier
{
     None = 0,
     Alt = 1,
     Control = 2,
     Shift = 4,
     WinKey = 8
}

public ExampleForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     int id = 0;     // The id of the hotkey. 
     RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id, (int)KeyModifier.Shift, Keys.A.GetHashCode());       // Register Shift + A as global hotkey. 
}
```

Comment: When you say "it fails", what exactly happens? Does your program error - if so, does it show a certain error message?

Comment: If the hotkey belongs to another application UnregisterHotKey is not going to work as it expects the key to have been previously registered by the calling thread - which is not the case.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Comment: Especially worth quoting this line from the article IInspectable linked - "When two programs "duke it out" like this, you can't predict which one will win, but you can predict with 100% certainty who will lose: The user."

Answer (score 0):

I agree with IInspectable (and obviously Raymond). You should avoid this. But if you absolutely must do this, I believe Windows Hooks using `SetWindowHookEx` is the way to go.

**System level hooks are serious stuff, and care should be taken when implementing them, since they affect system's performance.**.

For details and working code look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838540/detecting-ctrlv-with-registerhotkey-but-not-intercepting-it) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/7294/processing-global-mouse-and-keyboard-hooks-in-c).

**Do note again:** Its an overkill, and its like using a sledgehammer (or I would say Demolition hammer) to crack a nut. But sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do!